# How do I search database for text string?

Tags: sql-server, search

Is there any way to search a whole SQL Server database for a text string?

By *the whole database* I mean tables, views, stored procedures, etc.

Comment: In data or definitions or both? It matters **a lot**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to display / search all tables, columns and SPs with a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC SearchAllTables 
(
@SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

-- Copyright © 2013 Peter Nold. All rights reserved.
-- Purpose: To search all columns of all tables for a given search string

CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110), @myCount varchar(255)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

/* debug */
print '************************************************************'
print 'Starting Search For: ' + @SearchStr2
print '************************************************************'

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)                  
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN

            -- debug
            print 'Searching the field: ' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName

            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(max), ' + @ColumnName + '), 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE CONVERT(varchar(max), ' + @ColumnName + ') LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END 
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results

SET @myCount = 'Found in #columns: ' + cast((select count(*) from #Results) AS VARCHAR)
print '************************************************************'
print @myCount
print '************************************************************'

END

/* example to search for the text METZ:
 ***
exec SearchAllTables 'METZ'
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

If by database you *really* mean absolutely everything including procedure source code, the easiest will likely be to generate a DB dump and to search for the string within the resulting file. This will be simpler than running all sorts of queries on the information schema.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to search certain texts in stored proc

```
SELECT Distinct SO.Name
FROM sysobjects SO (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN syscomments SC (NOLOCK) on SO.Id = SC.ID
AND SO.Type = 'P'
AND SC.Text LIKE '%test%'
ORDER BY SO.Name
```

Comment: Thanx for this hint. Since I am searching sometimes over several topics / bases, it would be helpful to get a "at a glance" overview to be able to distinct, if it's a stored procedure to be run or a view to be shown.